# Solving a recurrence T(n) = 2T(n/2) + sqrt(n)

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

Need a little help! This is what I have so far using backward substitution:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + sqrt(n), where T(1) = 1, and n = 2^k
T(n) = 2[2T(n/4) + sqrt(n/2)] + sqrt(n) = 2^2T(n/4) + 2sqrt(n/2) + sqrt(n)
T(n) = 2^2[2T(n/8) + sqrt(n/4)] + 2sqrt(n/2) + sqrt(n)
     = 2^3T(n/8) + 2^2sqrt(n/4) + 2sqrt(n/2) + sqrt(n)
```

In general

```
T(n) = 2^kT(1) + 2^(k-1) x sqrt(2^1) + 2^(k-2) x sqrt(2^2) + ... + 2^1 x sqrt(2^(k-1)) + sqrt(2^k)
```

Is this right so far? If it is, I can not figure out how to simplify it and reduce it down to a general formula.

I'm guessing something like this? Combining the terms

```
= 1 + 2^(k-(1/2)) + 2^(k-(2/2)) + 2^(k-(3/2)) + ... + 2^((k-1)/2) + 2^(k/2)
```

And this is where I'm stuck. Maybe a way to factor out a 2^k?
Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) could do this if you are looking for a big-O solution.

Comment: Replace `n` with `2^k`, at each iteration you get first `2^(k-1)`, then `2^(k-2)` and eventually `2^0`. You have `k` calls, `k` being `log2(n)`... thus complexity of `T(n)` is `O(log(n))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're half way there.
The expression can be simplified to this:

[image]

Comment: Ah ha, so n + n/sqrt(2) + n/sqrt(4) + .. + 1 = sqrt(n)*(sqrt(2n)-1)*(sqrt(2)+1)? Do you know if there is a general summation formula used to generate that?

Comment: @user1201359 look for sum of geometric series

Comment: Okay, I'll try to work out the general formula, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want just a big-O solution, then [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) is just fine.

If you want a exact equation for this, a [recursion tree](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/lec20.html) is good. like this:

[image]

The right hand-side is cost for every level, it's easy to find a general form for the cost, which is `sqrt((2^h) * n)`.  Then, sum up the cost you could get T(n).

1. According to Master Theorem, it's case 1, so `O(n)`.
2. According to Recursion Tree, the exact form should be `sqrt(n)*(sqrt(2n)-1)*(sqrt(2)+1)`, which corresponds with the big-O notation.

EDIT:

The recursion tree is just a visualized form of the so called `backward substitution`.  If you sum up the right hand side, i.e. the `cost`, you could get the generalized form of `T(n)`.  All these methods could found in `introduction to algorithm`

Comment: Isn't it rather `O(log(n))`?

Comment: I do need an exact formula, but the teacher is expecting it to be worked out like above using backward substitution. I think I'm on the right track, I just need to figure out how to factor and simplify it.

Comment: @ring0 Why O(log(n))? According to Master Theorem, this satisfies the case 1, so it should be O(n).

Comment: @user1201359 the substitution is just another version of the recursion tree, basically they share the same idea.  Recursion tree is just a visualized representation.  You could actually get the substitution form from the recursion tree.

Comment: @user1201359 Sorry, a factor is missing. see the updated.

Comment: Edit: seen updated. Matches!

Comment: I'm looking at your link for the recursion tree but they don't go into detail about how to come up with the final formula, they just say how to find the BigO. Would you be able to include the steps up to your exact form?

Comment: @gongzhitaao the question specifically asks for a substitution method, not for alternatives. Besides, there is no answer here.

Comment: @user1201359 First you have to understand the recursion tree.  If you could understand that, the final T(n) is just the sum of the right-hand cost.

Comment: @icepack Sorry for the answer posted.  I will be more carefull next time.  But substitution and recursion tree are actually the same thing, as I've said, recursion tree is just a visualized representation of the substitution.

Comment: @icepack What do you mean by no answer here?  And also, OP needs exact form instead of big-O notation which could be achieved easily with Master Theorem.